# I have data at 3 time points, what analysis should I use to compare them?

Tags: r, time-series, anova

I have data at 3 time points, should I do time-series analysis?

I have two populations of mice that need to be compared. They were both fed a similar diet but one was fed extra oats. I collected the fecal samples at time point 0, then in 2 weeks, and then in 2 weeks again. I want to compare if their the changes in their fecal microbiome through time differed between the two populations. I'm not sure what analysis I should use. I think the time points are not sufficient for a time series, but if so do I just use an ANOVA for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have longitudinal data, not time-series data (time series involves measurements on one variable across time, while longitudinal involve multiple subjects measured over time).

You could certainly use ANOVA treating the three times as categorical variables. `aov(fecal ~ factor(time)*diet + Error(mouse/factor(time)))` will fit such a model.